# Subversive connectors not working with newest Ganymede update

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-3.4, subversive, ganymede

I'm using Subversive plugin in Ganymede, but after today's update it stopped working - it just doesn't see any valid svn connectors (I've already been using 1.2.0 dev version of SVNKit, instead of a stable one, because Subversive / Ganymede could not handle it; now it can't handle even the dev one). Any ideas how to make it work? Are subversive guys releasing a new version of their plugin / connectors soon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem right after the update. It turned out that I had been getting the connectors (the base connector and both the SVNKit and JavaHL connectors) from the Polarion site that had "ganymede" in the URL. Instead, I should have been using the general URL.

Checking my current configuration, you should be using this update URL:

```
http://www.polarion.org/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/
```

The one I had been using, that should be deprecated if you are using it, is:

```
http://www.polarion.org/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/ganymede-site/
```

Note the difference. Once I changed that, I was able to download the 2.0.3 versions of the connectors, and Subversion again worked for me.

Comment: Pawel, this was the answer for me (hint hint)

(If I could have given you 10 votes up I would ;-)

Comment: Saved my life.  Seriously, could Subversive be any more complicated to install?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) in Ganymede successfully, maybe could you switch? I do recall having problems with SvnKit also, I'm using the JavaHL client.